# Is it possible to change Ethereum wallet password using Java(web3j)?

Tags: java, blockchain, ethereum, go-ethereum, web3-java

I have created an ether wallet address using Java(web3j). Now i want to change the wallet password but, i am not able to change it.

Is there any possible way to change the Ether wallet password using Java(web3j)?

Answer (score 0):

No its not possible yet.

Accordint to the the [doc](https://docs.web3j.io/transactions.html#creating-and-working-with-wallet-files)

> web3j is able to both generate a new secure Ethereum wallet file for you, or work with an existing wallet file.

But there is no mention of updating wallet file anywhere. And also [WalletUtils](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/blob/master/crypto/src/main/java/org/web3j/crypto/WalletUtils.java) does not have any wallet update option.

One solution could be making an API to run a bash file with `geth account update "targetAddress"` command